# Is there any significant performance difference between Query and QueryRow in the sql package?

Tags: go

Is there any significant performance difference between the

```
func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)
```

and the

```
func (db *DB) QueryRow(query string, args ...interface{}) *Row
```

in the `"database/sql"` package even if you have `LIMIT 1;` at the end of your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the overhead of a function call (i.e., almost nothing, compared to sending a query to your database). QueryRow calls Query, and then wraps the results in an sql.Row.

Comment: @Alex, use [the source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.5/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1024-L1030) (also see [`Row.Scan`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.5/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1728-L1773)).